# Google drive bash to move / copy google-based file: Operation not permitted

Tags: bash, google-drive

Does anyone of you know how (and if) i can use `cp` `mv` to move google-based file (`.gsheet` `.gdocs` etc) within the `/Volumes` of Google drive?

```
mv website\ 4.gslides website\ 42.gslides
mv: cannot move 'website 4.gslides' to 'website 42.gslides': Operation not supported
```

it seem sto work for normal files, not for google based files

the volume is mounted like this

`//DRIVE@localhost:49241/stefano%40example.com%20-%20Google%20Drive on /Volumes/GoogleDrive (smbfs, nodev, nosuid, nobrowse, mounted by stefano)`

Comment: How are you mounting Google Drive? If unsure, the command `mount` might show that in the output, you can add that line to your question.

Comment: updated the post with the output